# Panel with Next and Previous buttons

Tags: wpf, user-controls, autosize, panels

Hello pplwould like to know if we can do a panel like this in WPF.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcSWG.png]

Where I sent a list item for the usercontrol, and after that the control showed items that were possible, and if more it shows the next and previous buttons. In windows forms I have. Now wpf in that complicated. I can not show items as monitor size user even knowing how many are being presented, he puts her items and then can not do paging. Can you help me?

Cumps

Comment: A bit vulgar http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=cumps

Comment: From what i understand you could use a datatemplate to show all the items you have in your list. Something like this http://wpftutorial.net/DataTemplates.html

Comment: Or maybe something more in the lines of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8308903/itemscontrol-datatemplate-items-showing-side-by-side

Answer (score 0):

You could have a horizontal `StackPanel` in the grid and scroll the `StackPanel` with two buttons.